# How can I change title using php?

Tags: php

I have my index.php in which I am including the header. But the problem is that I want a different header title as I am including it in other pages well. I want it to change dynamically according to page like if its other page like shop then title should be Toys - Shop like this. I am new to PHP can anyone please help me with how to do it? Index.php:

```
<?php include'headernav.php';?>
  <div class="header-outs" id="home">
     <div class="header-bar">
        <div class="info-top-grid">
           <div class="info-contact-agile">
              <ul>
                 <li>
                    <span class="fas fa-phone-volume"></span>
                    <p>+(000)123 4565 32</p>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                    <p><a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example1.com</a></p>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Headernav.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
   <head>
      <title>Toys-Home</title>
      <!--meta tags -->
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="keywords" content="" />
      <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all">
      <!--//stylesheets-->
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunflower:500,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
<body>
```

Comment: Maybe you can include part of the pathname of the file into the filename: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: How can i do that. Can you please help by answering?

Comment: `<title><?= $title ?></title>` and define the variable `$title` before

Comment: But my php is common for all.

Comment: If i change for one it will change all of them

Comment: Do you mean you have ONLY ONE php code for ALL your pages?

Comment: Yes, i have included this in all

Comment: You know you can do this : `$title = 'My Super Page!'; include("Headernav.php");` ?

Comment: But i am writing title in headernav.php

Comment: I want to know the correct way

Comment: One solution would be to write a helper function where you pass the title. function generic_headernav($title = 'Home') then you rewrite your headernav and make the title dynamic like <?php echo $title ?> . Or you go to rewrite your code in MVC Pattern.

Comment: Yes, It can also be done like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

index.php:

```
<?php 
$pagename = 'Toys-Home';
include ('headernav.php');?>
  <div class="header-outs" id="home">
     <div class="header-bar">
        <div class="info-top-grid">
           <div class="info-contact-agile">
              <ul>
                 <li>
                    <span class="fas fa-phone-volume"></span>
                    <p>+(000)123 4565 32</p>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                    <p><a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example1.com</a></p>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

headernav.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
   <head>
      <title><?php print $pagename; ?></title>
      <!--meta tags -->
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="keywords" content="" />
      <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all">
      <!--//stylesheets-->
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunflower:500,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
<body>
```

You'd have to set the $pagename variable on each page if that's something you're looking for. Each page would have the title you've set in that variable.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I used to think you can't declare variables like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Loupeznik's accepted answer provides a solution. An alternative is to use functions in include files and call them from the main PHP. You will have to write a bit more code, but you will get more flexibility. E.g. you will be able to add different css or js files on different pages letter or use a single include file for both header and footer or other common PHP code.

The way to do this is to add a function called writeHeaderNav() or something similar and then call it from index.php with $pagename as an argument.

headernav.php

```
<?php
function writeHeaderNav($pagetitle){
echo"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='zxx'>
   <head>
      <title>$pagetitle</title>
      <!--meta tags -->
      <meta charset='UTF-8'>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
      <meta name='keywords' content='' />
      <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all'>
      <!--//stylesheets-->
      <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunflower:500,700' rel='stylesheet'>
      <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet'>
   </head>
<body>";

}

//you can have other PHP code here if needed
function writeFooter(){
    //echo html for common footer
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
    $pagename = 'Toys-Home';
    include ('headernav.php');
    writeHeaderNav($pagename);
    // or you can use writeHeaderNav('Toys-Home');
?>
 <div class="header-outs" id="home">
<!--rest of code-->
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You can put a variable like this in your Headernav.php file and have it defined before your include

< title> < ?php echo "$my_title"; ?>

2. This variable can be changed by the way you get it

- from your url ($_GET)
- from a sql query
- from a session variable
- ...